# Which -all svmtrain doesn't show libsvm's svmtrain

Tags: macos, matlab

i'm trying to use libsvm's svmtrain. i've got libsvm with mex files included. i run matlab 2013a on mac osx 10.10.2 with xcode 4.4
i checked gcc and it says :

> Configured with: --prefix=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr
>   --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1 Apple LLVM version 6.1.0 (clang-602.0.53) (based on LLVM 3.6.0svn) Target:
>   x86_64-apple-darwin14.1.1 Thread model: posix

and when i run the code included svmtrain it says:

> .Error using svmtrain (line 233) Y must be a vector or a character
>   array. Error in train (line 47)   model = svmtrain(scores_train',
>   feats_train', ['-s 4 -c ' num2str(C) ' -t 0 -q']);

and mex -setup says:

Options files control which compiler to use, the compiler and link command
    options, and the runtime libraries to link against.

```
Using the 'mex -setup' command selects an options file that is
placed in /Users/hossein/.matlab/R2013a and used by default for 'mex'. An options 
file in the current working directory or specified on the command line 
overrides the default options file in /Users/hossein/.matlab/R2013a.

To override the default options file, use the 'mex -f' command
(see 'mex -help' for more information).
```

The options files available for mex are:
  1: /Applications/MATLAB_R2013a.app/bin/mexopts.sh : 
      Template Options file for building MEX-files
  0: Exit with no changes

and which -all svmtrain :
which -all svmtrain
/Applications/MATLAB_R2013a.app/toolbox/stats/stats/svmtrain.m

i've also added libsvm to path. and tried many ways i've found on the internet but problem still remains. what should i do that matlab recognise libsvm's svmtrain?(it already added to top of the path)

tnx in advance

Comment: actually xcode is 6 beta 3 and i forgot to change it , sry :-)

Comment: Any errors when compiling? Are the mex files generated? (e.g. `svmtrain.mexmaci64`)

Comment: it says Y must be a vector or a character array. and there are  trainsvm.mexa64 and predictsvm.mexa64 included in libsvm... when i use this libsvm in windows it wroks well but in mac it says  Y must be a vector or a character array.

Comment: The precompiled files don't work on Mac OS X, as they are compiled for Windows. On Mac, you'll need to compile the MEX-files yourself. Open the folder containing all source files in MATLAB and call `make`.

Comment: make says :
 mex:  libsvmread.c  not a normal file or does not exist.
If make.m failes, please check README about detailed instructions.